# Drawing a logical gate diagram with the circuitikz package

Tags: circuitikz

My goal is to have a diagram which looks like this:
[image: result]

I would like to accomplish this with the circuitikz-package. So far I have already written this piece of code:

```
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
    (0,2) node[and port] (and) {}
    (0,0) node[xor port] (xor) {}
    (and.in 1) node[above left=.5cm](a) {$a_0$}
    (and.in 2) node[below left = .5cm](b) {$b_0$}
    (and.out) node[below](s) {$s_1$}
    (xor.out) node[below](s) {$s_0$}    
    (a) -| (and.in 1)
    (b) -| (and.in 2)
    (a) -| (xor.in 1)
    (b) -| (xor.in 2);  
\end{circuitikz}
```

Which leads to this result:
[image: result_so_far]

I would be more than happy, if you could help me to get the second image look more like the first one. Many thanks!

Edit: I just managed to get an image which is a bit better, by changing the position in the third line from (0,0) to (2,2)

Since this is just a dirty hack which dosn't scale to more complex diagrams, I would still appreciate help for a more general solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main change is to have separate x coordinates for the vertical lines, changing e.g.

```
(a) -| (and.in 1)
(a) -| (xor.in 1)
```

to

```
(a) -- +(0.5,0) |- (and.in 1)
(a) -- +(0.5,0) |- (xor.in 1)
```

To make the circuit look even more like the sample circuit, one might want to move `a_0` down.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
    (0,2) node[and port] (and) {}
    (0,0) node[xor port] (xor) {}
    (and.in 1) node[below left=.5cm](a) {$a_0$}
    (and.in 2) node[below left = .5cm](b) {$b_0$}
    (and.out) node[below](s) {$s_1$}
    (xor.out) node[below](s) {$s_0$}    
    (a) -- +(0.5,0) |- (and.in 1)
    (b) -| (and.in 2)
    (a) -- +(0.5,0) |- (xor.in 1)
    (b) -| (xor.in 2);  
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```